# Android App to Toggle Keyguard (aka Lockscreen and Screen Lock)

Tags: gratis, android, lockscreen

Can someone recommend a free-of-charge Android (KitKat) app that will enable/disable the Keyguard (aka Lockscreen and Screen Lock)?

The Keyguard is the screen that appears after you have let your Android device sit idle for a configurable period of time.

I want to quickly toggle the setting that enables/disables the Keyguard.

Must not present any ads when it performs the toggle.

Requiring root is acceptable.  Slight preference for unrooted, but I think this type of functionality will require root.

Also, must not be always running.  A simple toggle using an icon is all I want.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `toggle`. Is it just activating the lock screen like what the power button does? You do not need a rooted device to do that, just an app with administrative rights. Tasker can accomplish that, but it's not free

Comment: @Timmy Thanks for letting me know that my words were not clear.  I'll fix it... okay, fixed! :-)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you were talking about the setting and not the actual lock screen

Comment: @Timmy Yes, it wasn't clear as it was originally written!  Thanks for bringing it to my attention.  :-)

Comment: Why not just use the power button - it is always there, doesn't run anything and works on unrooted devices?

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no free-of-charge tool doing that. Can be done with *Tasker* and the *SecureSettings* Plugin, but that combi doesn't come for free. Comparable things are "Keep Screen On" (effectively disabling Keyguard along the lines). Hint: Use [IzzyOnDroid Search](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/search) for "Tools" having the `DISABLE_KEYGUARD` permission, restricting to "free only" – and see what that turns up I might have missed some (oh, looks like Elixier might be able doing that). For more results, the StripSearch app has a permission filter as well :)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks... BTW, you've got the https in there again!  :-)

Comment: @SteveBarnes Steve, unfortunately the power button can be easily pressed in a pocket... hence the need for a Keyguard lockscreen.  But sometimes, especially when texting back and forth, having to press the power button and then perform the Keyguard task (password, swipe, pattern, et al) is disruptive to the workflow.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard ouch. CopyPasta, sorry. Luckily you already know your way around that. Time to find a sponsor for a good certificate :)

Comment: @Izzy Lol... not a problem, my friend.  :-)